# How to set scrollable button for multiple buttons in android?

Tags: android, scrollable

I have 5 buttons i want to scroll them all the buutons,my code is

> ```
>                     <Button
>                      android:id="@+id/btnAll"
>                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                      android:layout_width="80dip"
>                      android:text="All"
>                      android:background="@drawable/green1" /> 
>                      <Button
>                      android:id="@+id/btnBarAndRes"
>                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                      android:layout_width="80dip"
>                      android:text="Bar Restaurants"
>                      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnAll"
>                      android:background="@drawable/green1" /> 
>                      <Button
>                      android:id="@+id/btnFashion"
>                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                      android:layout_width="80dip"
>                      android:text="FashionBeauty"
>                      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnBarAndRes"
>                      android:background="@drawable/green1"/> 
>                      <Button
>                      android:id="@+id/btnParty"
>                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                      android:layout_width="80dip"
>                      android:text="PartyEntertainment"
>                      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnFashion"
>                      android:background="@drawable/green1"
>                       /> 
>                       <Button
>                      android:id="@+id/btnLife"
>                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                      android:layout_width="80dip"
>                      android:text="Life Style"
>                      android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnParty"
>                      android:background="@drawable/green1"
>                       /> 
>                  </RelativeLayout>   
>    </ScrollView>
>          </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <HorizontalScrollView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
                    android:orientation="horizontal" 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                                    <Button
                                 android:id="@+id/btnAll"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_width="80dip"
                                 android:text="All"
                                 android:background="@drawable/icon" /> 
                                 <Button
                                 android:id="@+id/btnBarAndRes"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_width="80dip"
                                 android:text="Bar Restaurants"
                                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnAll"
                                 android:background="@drawable/icon" /> 
                                 <Button
                                 android:id="@+id/btnFashion"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_width="80dip"
                                 android:text="FashionBeauty"
                                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnBarAndRes"
                                 android:background="@drawable/icon"/> 
                                 <Button
                                 android:id="@+id/btnParty"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_width="80dip"
                                 android:text="PartyEntertainment"
                                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnFashion"
                                 android:background="@drawable/icon"
                                  /> 
                                  <Button
                                 android:id="@+id/btnLife"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_width="80dip"
                                 android:text="Life Style"
                                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnParty"
                                 android:background="@drawable/icon"
                                  /> 

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just keep all the buttons in one layout(Relative layout) and keep this layout within scrollview. now all the buttons within layout will scroll.

```
<RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView>
 <RelativeLayout>
   <Button>
        //Place code for button1
    </Button> 
     <Button>
        //Place code for button2
    </Button> 
  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That code will not operate properly. It should be `</Button>` Not `</Buttons>`